# Safe Stack with d3.js

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I am trying to integrate a data visualization created with d3 inside the SAFE stack default template.

As a prooj of concept, I am trying to integrate this bar chart: http://fable.io/fable-graphics/samples/d3/barchart/index.html

I have been able to insert the code for the bar chart into client.fs:

```
let svg = Fable.Import.D3.Globals.select("#display")
                                 .append("svg")
                                 .attr("width", U3.Case1 width)
                                 .attr("height", U3.Case1 height)
```

Everything compiles and runs fine, but I can't figure out how to actually make the image visible on the generated page.

I am guessing it has to be inserted into the view:

```
let view (model : Model) (dispatch : Msg -> unit) =
    div []
        [ Navbar.navbar [ Navbar.Color IsPrimary ]
            [ Navbar.Item.div [ ]
                [ Heading.h2 [ ]
                    [ str "SAFE Template" ] ] ]
......
```

but I have made a few attempts and can't get things to compile.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was actually pretty easy.

All that was needed was to change the selector from "#display" to something that is guranteed to exist like "body" like so

```
let svg = Fable.Import.D3.Globals.select("body")
```